# how do i get error message to print before new request on second try

Tags: if-statement

I need to get the error message to print out if you enter a number not between 1 and 10 and then ask for the number again. Currently this is printing the request first then the error message.

package loopcode;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author SClough
 */
public class Loopcode
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userinput;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10; ");
        userinput = scanner.nextInt();

        if ((userinput <= 1  || userinput >= 10 )) 
        {
            System.err.print("The number you entered was not between 1 and 10!");
        }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Good job! The number you enterred is " + userinput +".");

            }

    }
        while (userinput <= 1  || userinput >= 10 );
 }
```

}

Comment: This line `if ((userinput <= 1  || userinput >= 10 )); {` should be `if ((userinput <= 1  || userinput >= 10 )) {` without the `;` before the `{`.

Comment: that took care of the if without else error but I am still getting the reached end of file while parsing error

Comment: Formatting and indenting the code will help a lot in spotting other syntax errors. Please consider doing so. I believe there is an unmatched `{`.

Comment: I figured that one out I was missing an end bracket.  I have another question.  This is running the please enter a number between 1 and 10 and if I enter 11 it prints please enter a number between 1 and 10 again before the error message is there a way to get the error message to print firs?

Comment: Could you please provide a (properly formatted) minimal working example? Please consider editing your question or ask a new one.

Comment: updated the code and question

Comment: is the stray `{` between the two blocks of code actually part of the code? if so, please fix.